# How can I avoid showing a page for a fraction of a second before angular ui-router redirects to another page?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state, resolve

I am using angular ui-router for routing and ng-token-auth for authentication on my website. If a signed in user tries to visit sign-in page, then he should be redirected to home page (code below).

```
$stateProvider
.state('sign-in',{
    url: '/sign-in',
    templateUrl: 'partials/registrations/sign-in.html',
    controller: 'SigninCtrl as signin',
    resolve: {
      auth: function($auth, $state) {
        $auth.validateUser().then(function(){
          $state.go('home');
        });
      }
    }
  })
```

This works fine on state change or when I refresh the page. However, when I open the sign-in link on a new tab, it shows sign-in page for a fraction of a second and then redirects to home page.

How can I avoid showing sign-in page view before redirection?

Answer (score 0):

```
$stateProvider
.state('sign-in',{
    url: '/sign-in',
    templateUrl: 'partials/registrations/sign-in.html',
    controller: 'SigninCtrl as signin',
    resolve: {
      auth: function($auth, $state, $timeout) {
        var promise = $auth.validateUser();
        promise.then(function(){
          $timeout(function() {
             $state.go('home');
          });
        });
        return promise;
      }
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **State Change Event** - `stateChangeStart` .

`$stateChangeStart` - fired when the transition begins.

```
angular.module('MyApp').run(function($rootScope, $state) {
    // Check authentication before changing state
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        // do authentication work here
    });
});
```

For more help - https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki